# ncurses on Mac OS X: attron(A_BOLD) has no effect

Tags: macos, ncurses

I was following [this tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html) and the problem is that I cannot get ncurses to output **bold** text. My tiny program that exhibits this is

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    initscr();

    attron(A_BOLD);
    printw("Hello.\n");

    attroff(A_BOLD);
    printw("World.\n");

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I use ***Mac OS X***, and the command I compile the above program with is

```
gcc example.c -o example -lncurses
```

which compiles without errors and warnings.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any other way of printing bold font?
2. Why does this happen?

Comment: It depends on your terminal program and the terminal description (set with `TERM`).  In a quick check, the program works for me.

Comment: Should I set TERM to xterm-color?

Comment: What terminal program are you using, and what is `TERM` set to now?

Comment: Your program works for me (`TERM` is `xterm-256color` here). Since you asked, there's another way using [ANSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): `/bin/echo -e "\x1b[1mTEST\x1b[0m"` but that won't work if your program doesn't.

Comment: I use the default Terminal.app. From the Preferences I tried `xterm-16color` and `xterm-256color`. None of them worked for me. For some reason I do not have `xterm` (without that color string).

Comment: It should work, given that information.  If you have altered the color palette in Terminal.app, it may cause bold text to not look bold (or some odd choice of font).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just make sure that the option **Use bold fonts** is checked. Also, some fonts seem not to support **bold** effect.

Comment: For what it's worth, that is a default setting in each profile.